# Using a column as row names and set the other columns as binary values based on strings

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I need one of my columns to be set as row name, accounting for duplicates, and the other columns should be separated by unique values into new columns assuming binary values if they are related to the row name.

Example:

ORIGINAL DATAFRAME

```
df <- data.frame(module = c("M1","M1","M1","M1","M1","M2"),
                  GO = c("inflama","inflama","ciclo","inflama","ciclo","sinapse"),
                  gene = c("PPARG","RELA","RELA","IRF5","ACKR1","GATA3"))

> df
  module      GO  gene
1     M1 inflama PPARG
2     M1 inflama  RELA
3     M1   ciclo  RELA
4     M1 inflama  IRF5
5     M1   ciclo ACKR1
6     M2 sinapse GATA3
```

FINAL DATAFRAME

```
df2 <- data.frame(gene = c("PPARG","RELA","IRF5","ACKR1","GATA3"),
                   M1 = c(1,1,1,1,0),
                   M2 = c(0,0,0,0,1),
                   inflama = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                   ciclo = c(0,1,0,1,0), sinapse = c(0,0,0,0,1))
> df2
   gene M1 M2 inflama ciclo sinapse
1 PPARG  1  0       1     0       0
2  RELA  1  0       1     1       0
3  IRF5  1  0       1     0       0
4 ACKR1  1  0       0     1       0
5 GATA3  0  1       0     0       1
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may either use `pivot_wider` (from `tidyr`) to reshape or with `dummy_cols` (from `fastDummies`)

```
library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
 dummy_cols(c('module', 'GO'), remove_selected_columns = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(gene) %>% 
 summarise(across(everything(),  ~ + (any(.x)))) %>%
 rename_with(~ str_remove(., ".*_"), contains("_"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  gene     M1    M2 ciclo inflama sinapse
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>
1 ACKR1     1     0     1       0       0
2 GATA3     0     1     0       0       1
3 IRF5      1     0     0       1       0
4 PPARG     1     0     0       1       0
5 RELA      1     0     1       1       0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Matrix` package has a very efficient `fac2sparse` function for this purpose. If you downloaded R from CRAN, then you already have it installed. Here is an example of its usage:

```r
library("Matrix")
f <- gl(3, 2L, labels = letters[1:3])
f
## [1] a a b b c c
## Levels: a b c

fac2sparse(f)
## 3 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##              
## a 1 1 . . . .
## b . . 1 1 . .
## c . . . . 1 1
```

To include the resulting matrix in a long format data frame, you would transpose it with `t` and coerce it from sparse to dense format with `as(Class="matrix")`.

```r
fac2dense <- function(x) as(t(fac2sparse(x)), "matrix")
data.frame(f, fac2dense(f))
##   f a b c
## 1 a 1 0 0
## 2 a 1 0 0
## 3 b 0 1 0
## 4 b 0 1 0
## 5 c 0 0 1
## 6 c 0 0 1
```

Putting this into practice, I would transform your data frame `df` in two steps, like so:

```r
df_bin <- data.frame(df["gene"], fac2dense(df[["module"]]), fac2dense(df[["GO"]]))
df_bin
```

```
   gene M1 M2 ciclo inflama sinapse
1 PPARG  1  0     0       1       0
2  RELA  1  0     0       1       0
3  RELA  1  0     1       0       0
4  IRF5  1  0     0       1       0
5 ACKR1  1  0     1       0       0
6 GATA3  0  1     0       0       1
```

```r
aggregate(. ~ gene, df_bin, max)
```

```
   gene M1 M2 ciclo inflama sinapse
1 ACKR1  1  0     1       0       0
2 GATA3  0  1     0       0       1
3  IRF5  1  0     0       1       0
4 PPARG  1  0     0       1       0
5  RELA  1  0     1       1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think calling `pivot_wider` twice is good enough here.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = module,
                values_from = module,
                values_fill = 0,
                values_fn = \(x)1) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = GO,
                values_from = GO,
                values_fill = 0,
                values_fn = \(x)1)

# A tibble: 5 × 6
  gene     M1    M2 inflama ciclo sinapse
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 PPARG     1     0       1     0       0
2 RELA      1     0       1     1       0
3 IRF5      1     0       1     0       0
4 ACKR1     1     0       0     1       0
5 GATA3     0     1       0     0       1
```

If we want to make it a bit simpler, we can define a pivoting function:

```
pivoting<-function(x, y) pivot_wider(x,
                        names_from = y,
                        values_from = y,
                        values_fill = 0,
                        values_fn = \(x)1)
df %>%
    pivoting('module') %>%
    pivoting('GO')
```

But I think this is too much trouble as there is already a package for that. As mentioned by @akrun, I would go with `dummy_cols`

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` is also an option:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
```

Use `dcast()` to aggregate:

```
DT1 = dcast(df, gene ~ GO, fill = 0L, fun.agg = \(x) sum(!is.na(x)))

DT2 = dcast(df, gene ~ module, fill = 0L, fun.agg = \(x) ifelse(x == 0, 0, 1))
```

Then you can join the tables:

```
DT3 = DT1[DT2, on = "gene"]

DT3
```

Output

```
    gene ciclo inflama sinapse M1 M2
1: ACKR1     1       0       0  1  0
2: GATA3     0       0       1  0  1
3:  IRF5     0       1       0  1  0
4: PPARG     0       1       0  1  0
5:  RELA     1       1       0  1  0
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check out **dplyr**, **tidyr**, and **tidyverse** libraries for data wrangling in R.

```
## Loading the required libraries 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

## Creating a pivot table
df_pivot = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!gene, names_to = 'Attributes', values_to = "AttributeValue") %>% ## Wider to longer
  group_by(gene,AttributeValue) %>% ## Grouping
  summarise(Count = n()) %>% ## Aggregation
  pivot_wider(names_from = AttributeValue , values_from = Count) ## Longer to wider

## Replacing NA with 0
df_pivot[is.na(df_pivot)] = 0

df_pivot
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   gene [5]
  gene  ciclo    M1    M2 sinapse inflama
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>
1 ACKR1     1     1     0       0       0
2 GATA3     0     0     1       1       0
3 IRF5      0     1     0       0       1
4 PPARG     0     1     0       0       1
5 RELA      1     2     0       0       1
```

Comment: This does not get us the expected output